# SQL Server query : get the sum conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Given data

[image]

I need to come up to this by including `SalesNew` column:

[image]

`SalesNew` column will compute for the sum of each items sales based on their group number conditionally.

Example based on the table above. when the group number of item is 1, IT WILL JUST COPY OR RETAIN ITS SALES. When it is not 1, SalesNew column should get the sum of all items per group, like in the given example, salesNew displays 20 for item 3 and item 4 because it adds their sales that both having 10. So item 3 and 4 salesNew value is 20.

I know the sum function but this doesn't display the desired output. I hope anyone could help me out on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry:(. But I am unable to understand, could you please elaborate it with an example?

Comment: You have very clearly explained it now. I will try to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SUM(Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY [Group])`, with a combination of `CASE`:

```
SELECT *,
    salesNew = 
        CASE
            WHEN [Group] = 1 THEN Sales
            ELSE SUM(Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY [Group])
        END
FROM Data
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c276/1/0)

---

You could also use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    d.*, 
    salesNew = 
        CASE
            WHEN [Group] = 1 THEN Sales
            ELSE x.salesNew
        END
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT salesNew = SUM(Sales)
    FROM Data
    WHERE [Group] = d.[Group]
)x
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c276/3/0)

Comment: What can you recommend for better performance? I am trying your first code.

Comment: I'll go for the `CROSS APPLY` but just to make sure, you should conduct a test. BTW, I made an edit on the `CROSS APPLY` method.

Comment: The partition already worked, cross apply looks longer, is it really better to use it considering fast performance? I will try it also.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I prefer partition more as it is shorter , and no significant difference in terms of speed from cross apply. Thanks again! You are heaven sent. @wewesthemenace

Comment: Hello @wewesthemenace, I found a drawback in using partition, it is not summing the data when the column is not fully identical. Because I have changed the source column , the column I am basing now is a string column. please help, I tried cross apply but I am seem lost

Comment: @rickyProgrammer, can you elaborate more by providing sample data. I suggest you open a new question for this.

Comment: hi! here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157651/query-using-cross-apply-to-get-sum-conditionally