# SQL Query using Cross Apply to get Sum Conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cross-apply

**Output to be produced**

[image]

using this as reference but now with different scenario [SQL Server query : get the sum conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597690/sql-server-query-get-the-sum-conditionally)

**explanation:**

Item, Sales, and remarks columns are given column from a database, New Sales column is a formulated column where in, it is getting the sum of items with the same keyword remarks except the default n/a remarks.

(regardless the remarks is not fully identical, at least there's a common similarity like what is on the image above - item 5 has "new" in it, still it sums up with item 6 because of their similar keyword found "small")

**code used**

**FIRST OPTION- using partition** - This doesn't work because when the remarks is not identical to each other it will not get the sum properly (for item5 and item6)

```
 CASE
     WHEN ([remarks] not  like '%big%') AND ([remarks] not  like '%PAENGS%') 


     THEN sales 
     ELSE SUM(sales) OVER(PARTITION BY [remarks])
     END as 'New Sales'
```

**SECOND OPTION -using Cross Apply** - So it leave me to this, but I was lost as it is not getting the desired output.

```
 CROSS APPLY
     SELECT
        d.*, 
        NewSales = 
        CASE
        WHEN ([remarks] not like '%big%') or ([remarks] not like '%small%')
        THEN Sales 
        ELSE x.NewSales
        END


        FROM #MSRSuperFinal3  d
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT NewSales = SUM(Sales)
                    FROM #MSRSuperFinal3 
                    WHERE ([remarks] like  '%big%') or ([remarks] like  '%small%')
        )x
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: can you add some data instead of picture or give a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: @wewesthemenace please help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT *
FROM temp t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUM(sales)
    FROM temp
    WHERE
        remarks LIKE '%' + t.remarks + '%'
        OR t.remarks LIKE '%' + remarks + '%'
)x(NewSales)
WHERE remarks <> 'n/a'

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 
    NewSales = sales
FROM temp
WHERE remarks = 'n/a'
ORDER BY item
```

---

Based on your comment, this should be your final query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #MSRSuperFinal3 t
CROSS APPLY( 
    SELECT 
        SUM(CurrentMonth)
    FROM #MSRSuperFinal3 
    WHERE 
        t.misc LIKE '%' + misc + '%'
        OR misc LIKE '%' + t.misc + '%'
)x(NewSales) 
WHERE 
    ([misc] LIKE '%BIGKAHUNA%') 
    or ([misc] LIKE '%PAENGS%') 

UNION ALL 
SELECT *, 
    NewSales = CurrentMonth 
FROM #MSRSuperFinal3 
WHERE 
    ([misc] not like '%BIGKAHUNA%')
    AND ([misc] not like '%PAENGS%')
    AND ([misc] not like '%ROBINSONS%')
ORDER BY location, name
```

Comment: Hi, what is the temp here stand for? a temporary table?

Comment: Oh, it's just a placeholder for your table `#MSRSuperFinal3`.

Comment: I follow your codes and replace the necessary columns to be replaced based on my original columns, and it didnt work. :(

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: First, what I understand is, the first query with cross apply is getting the items / tenants which are subject for getting the sum computation, then the second one will be the rest except the selected items in the first, they they will be combined using UNION ALL. I modified some because in the actual data, it's not always "N/A" some are blank space / empty, some are just "na", "none" and many more, so here's what I have done based on your code.

Comment: SELECT *
      FROM #MSRSuperFinal3
      CROSS APPLY(
       SELECT SUM(CurrentMonth)
       FROM #MSRSuperFinal3
       WHERE   ([misc] LIKE '%BIGKAHUNA%')
         --AND ([misc] LIKE '%PAENGS%')
      )x(NewSales)
      WHERE ([misc] LIKE '%BIGKAHUNA%')
         or ([misc] LIKE '%PAENGS%')

      UNION ALL

      SELECT *, 
       NewSales = CurrentMonth 
      FROM #MSRSuperFinal3
      WHERE ([misc] not like '%BIGKAHUNA%') AND ([misc] not like '%PAENGS%') AND ([misc] not like '%ROBINSONS%')
      ORDER BY location, name

Comment: Your query is different from mine. Use `LIKE` in the `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82159/discussion-between-rickyprogrammer-and-wewesthemenace).

Answer (score 0):

Try **Left Join** clause instead of Cross Apply:

```
SELECT a.item,
       a.sales,
       a.remarks,
       CASE
           WHEN a.remarks = 'n/a' 
           THEN a.sales
           ELSE SUM( b.sales )
       END AS [New Sales]
FROM query_using_cross_apply_to_get_sum_conditionally a
LEFT JOIN query_using_cross_apply_to_get_sum_conditionally b 
      ON(a.remarks LIKE '%' + b.remarks + '%'
         AND b.remarks != 'n/a')
GROUP BY a.item, a.sales, a.remarks;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CASE
    WHEN (a.[remarks] <> 'n/a') THEN a.sales 
    ELSE 
    (
        SELECT SUM(b.sales) 
        FROM #MSRSuperFinal3 b
        WHERE b.[remark] LIKE '%' + a.[remarks] + '%'
    )
END as 'New Sales'
```

Note that i just added a table alias so that the query knows which remark to use where. Otherwise something that might be faster is doing a Common table expression and firstly doing a sum for sales that contain each other, so for each unique remark sum all sales that contain in, and then in your last select you cna merely join on your common table expression table.